# How to send Zip file using UUENCODE in unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I need to send an e-mail with attachment as a zip file(containing multiple files zipped) using UUENCODE in UNIX(ksh). The mail has to send to multiple users with subject and a mail body. I tried with UUENCODE using the below command, but it is not working.

```
uuencode $zip_name $zip_name.zip | mailx -s "Mail Subject" "user@mail.com" 

- where $zip_name is name of the zip file.
```

How do I go ahead with this?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Don't use `uuencode`: it puts spaces at the ends of lines and some mail systems used to strip those off.  It isn't as robust a format as Base-64 encoding.

Comment: So what is the alternative for attaching a zip file  and sending mails?

Comment: "it is not working" - If you don't say exactly how plus whatever error messages you're getting then we have to guess.

Comment: There are no error messages Dennis. The mailing in not firing.

Answer (score 1):

Odds on you're getting too much data for a mail body.  Try using `split(1)` to split it up, or even better look on the web for the various incarnations of `shar` and make a shar file.  Many of those will split the file automagically.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.terrencemiao.com/Webmail/msg00881.html) on using UUENCODE/UUDECODE and [sharutils](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/sharutils.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that the file cannot be located. Otherwise the below code would work just fine.

```
zip_name=some_file.zip
MESSAGE_BODY="Some text."
(printf "%s\n%s\n" "$MESSAGE_BODY"; uuencode $zip_name $zip_name)| mailx -s "${SUBJECT}" $TO
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution**

```
echo "Your message" | uuencode "/home/ubuntu/test.zip" | mailx -s 'Your Subject' mail@example.com
```